# How to make table fill the container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, responsiveness

There is a fixed size table to the left that acts "sticky" with a variable size table to the right that when it overflows should use a scroll bar.

My problem is the left table is fixed size and I want the right side table to be responsive and fill out the container to the remaining 100% size, which I don't really know how to do.

I want it to fill out the whole container no matter what size that container is. And it also has to be responsive, so it still looks ok when resizing the window (making it smaller). It must adapt to that too.

The code can be seen here: http://www.bootply.com/JtnSn5A3Mz#

Answer (score 2):

How about this..

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

/*for desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
#snap_scale {
  position: relative;
  top: -16px;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.history {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #222;
  border: 3px #47496C solid;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
#snap_index {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.history td {
  font-family: Cousine;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  text-align: right;
  min-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #BADFC7;
  padding-right: 7px;
}
#snap_values {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 95%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.history .history_header td {
  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
  color: rgba( 255,255,255,0.5);
  background: #444;
  text-align: center;
}
.green {
  color: #8ceab3 !important;
}
}

/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

/*for mobile */
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 601px){
#snap_scale {
  position: relative;
  top: -16px;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.history {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #222;
  border: 3px #47496C solid;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
#snap_index {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.history td {
  font-family: Cousine;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  text-align: right;
  min-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #BADFC7;
  padding-right: 7px;
}
#snap_values {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.history .history_header td {
  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
  color: rgba( 255,255,255,0.5);
  background: #444;
  text-align: center;
}
.green {
  color: #8ceab3 !important;
}
}


/*for tab */
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 1200px){
#snap_scale {
  position: relative;
  top: -16px;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.history {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #222;
  border: 3px #47496C solid;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
#snap_index {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.history td {
  font-family: Cousine;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  text-align: right;
  min-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #BADFC7;
  padding-right: 7px;
}
#snap_values {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.history .history_header td {
  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
  color: rgba( 255,255,255,0.5);
  background: #444;
  text-align: center;
}
.green {
  color: #8ceab3 !important;
}
}
```

**[Responsive Grid Demo](http://www.bootply.com/s2FMYymedJ)**

Comment: And also, if you shrink the window size, it does not look goof anymore. So...it's not that simple. :)

Comment: "Responsive" is the key here. So if you could help me with that, it would be great. I changed the initial question so everything should be clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want this to be put in a responsive table.
I have set this in this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/oqh5ckha/) for you using **Bootstrap's responsive table**.
But as you want it to still scroll the full width of the table you don't actually see that it is responsive, but you may have other plans or may want to change it at some time.
Interesting to see some trading info etc around here, I come from a trading back ground as a coder.

I hope this can get you started.

```
<div id="snap_values" class="bs-example history" data-example-id="simple-responsive-table">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>

    </thead>
<tbody>

<tr class="history_header">
<th scope="row" class="title_index">Time:</th>
<td class="s0">8:31</td><td class="s1">14:02</td><td class="s2">14:03</td><td class="s3">14:04</td><td class="s4">14:05</td><td class="s5">14:06</td><td class="s6">14:07</td><td class="s7">14:08</td><td class="s8">14:09</td><td class="s9">14:10</td><td class="s10">14:11</td><td class="s11">14:12</td><td class="s12">14:13</td><td class="s13">14:14</td><td class="s14">14:15</td><td class="s15">14:16</td><td class="s16">14:17</td><td class="s17">14:18</td><td class="s18">14:19</td><td class="s19">14:20</td><td class="s20">14:21</td><td class="s21">14:22</td><td class="s22">14:23</td><td class="s23">14:24</td><td class="s24">14:25</td><td class="s25">14:26</td><td class="s26">14:27</td><td class="s27">14:28</td><td class="s28">14:29</td><td class="s29">14:30</td> 
</tr>

<tr class="snap_totals">
<th scope="row" class="title_index">Total:</th>
<td class="s0 green">29M</td><td class="s1 red">-16M</td><td class="s2 red">-12M</td><td class="s3 red">-16M</td><td class="s4 green">9M</td><td class="s5 red">-120M</td><td class="s6 red">-109M</td><td class="s7 red">-96M</td><td class="s8 red">-104M</td><td class="s9 red">-137M</td><td class="s10 red">-152M</td><td class="s11 red">-158M</td><td class="s12 red">-183M</td><td class="s13 red">-185M</td><td class="s14 red">-185M</td><td class="s15 red">-185M</td><td class="s16 red">-282M</td><td class="s17 red">-282M</td><td class="s18 red">-282M</td><td class="s19 red">-282M</td><td class="s20 red">-282M</td><td class="s21 red">-282M</td><td class="s22 red">-282M</td><td class="s23 red">-282M</td><td class="s24 red">-282M</td><td class="s25 red">-283M</td><td class="s26 red">-285M</td><td class="s27 red">-285M</td><td class="s28 red">-285M</td><td class="s29 red">-285M</td>
</tr>
```